# How would setjmp/longjmp be implemented in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

I've just started looking at WebAssembly MVP, and notice that there is no access to the stack and stack pointer, or indeed any structured exception handling support (throw/catch) etc.

Given it is supposed to be a C compilation target, it surely must be possible to implement `setjmp` and `longjmp`, but I can't fathom how this can be done nicely.  How does this construct look in wast?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zero-cost exception handling isn't supported in the WebAssembly MVP.

C++ exception handling and `setjmp`/`longjmp` are currently implemented through Emscripten by having each `try` or "invoke" perform a call to JavaScript with a continuation to WebAssembly's C++ code. A throw then throws a JavaScript exception, which unwinds the stack and handles the "landingpad" where unwinding code lives (usually destructor calls and `catch` blocks). This means that every continuation receives a boolean value: exception path or regular path.

This is super expensive! If LLVM can't prove that a function call can't throw then its IR contains an `invoke` instruction, and Emscripten relies on this to insert exception handling code. The default in C++ is that anything can throw, so if you look at LLVM IR there are `invoke`s all over the place when you compile with exceptions.

Zero-cost [exception handling is being worked on at the moment](https://github.com/WebAssembly/exception-handling), so this situation should resolve eventually. This will be used to implement `setjmp`/`longjmp`. This can enable all of the defined behavior of `setjmp`/`longjmp`, namely unwinding the stack without calling C++ destructors. It does not, however, allow the undefined behavior case of jumping forward to a stack that was already unwound which is sometimes used to implement coroutines.

Comment: Aha! No wonder I couldn't figure it out! This is far from ideal, but to be fair I suppose the biggest win is that currently all major browser vendors are on board and shipping or will shortly ship the MVP.